# Link error on Visual Studio 2015 when using library built on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, linker-errors

I compiled [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) as static libraries on Visual Studio 2019(with platform toolset v142), then wrote a demo program linking the opencv libs, everything worked fine. But when I compiled the demo on Visual Studio 2015(with platform toolset v140), it complaint link error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: parvati_demo, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>opencv_imgproc342.lib(resize.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___libm_sse2_sincos_ referenced in function "void __cdecl cv::interpolateLanczos4(float,float *)" (?interpolateLanczos4@cv@@YAXMPAM@Z)
1>E:\CPPCode\projects\parvati_release1\build32\Release\parvati_demo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
2>------ Skipped Build: Project: ALL_BUILD, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration 
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 1 up-to-date, 1 skipped ==========
```

According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=We%27ve%20changed%20this%20behavior,14%20for%20all%20three%20versions.&text=You%20can%20mix%20binaries%20built%20by%20different%20versions%20of%20the%20toolset.); binary compatibility is assured across Visual Studio 2015/17/19:
[image]
and I found the function `cv::interpolateLanczos4` is defined as

```cpp
static inline void interpolateLanczos4( float x, float* coeffs )
{
    static const double s45 = 0.70710678118654752440084436210485;
    static const double cs[][2]=
    {{1, 0}, {-s45, -s45}, {0, 1}, {s45, -s45}, {-1, 0}, {s45, s45}, {0, -1}, {-s45, s45}};

    if( x < FLT_EPSILON )
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
            coeffs[i] = 0;
        coeffs[3] = 1;
        return;
    }

    float sum = 0;
    double y0=-(x+3)*CV_PI*0.25, s0 = std::sin(y0), c0= std::cos(y0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
    {
        double y = -(x+3-i)*CV_PI*0.25;
        coeffs[i] = (float)((cs[i][0]*s0 + cs[i][1]*c0)/(y*y));
        sum += coeffs[i];
    }

    sum = 1.f/sum;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++ )
        coeffs[i] *= sum;
}
```

wherein `std::sin()` and `std::cos()` are used, which are declared in `corecrt_math.h`. So, I guess that missed symbol is related with `libm` or `xxxcrt.lib`. Finally, I found a `ucrt.lib` in Windows 10 SDk, but it did not work either. Who can help me out?

Comment: At a guess, `__libm_sse2_sincos_` is a special implementation that employs SSE, that gets compiled depending on the available features present on the target architecture. You seem to have compiled the library without SSE support but are now targeting an architecture that uses SSE. You'll need to force your library to include the SSE version to resolve the linker import.

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the scope of the binary compatibility explained by Microsoft. What is compatible across compiler versions is a final executable (and associated DLLs) with any version of the C++ runtime. I.e. you can compile your application with VS2019 and use the C++ runtime library redistributable package that came with VS2017/15. This is something you care about only if you are using the [dynamically-linked runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/md-mt-ld-use-run-time-library?view=vs-2019). In practice this means that if for some reason you ship some executables compiled with VS2015/v140 toolset and some compiled with VS2017/v141 toolset, you only need to have the users install a single C++ runtime redistributable. This is a huge advantage if you do not control what exact version of the C++ runtime is present on the system (which can be the case in some embedded systems that accept third-party plugins which have to be distributed as DLLs and can not install other assets).

However all object files that form this final executable still need to be compiled with the same compiler major version. If you use [full program optimisation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=vs-2019), you even need to have matching minor compiler versions. In general, for C++ applications, it is highly recommended to make sure all translation units that will make up the final binary (including associated DLLs) are compiled with the exact same compiler.

### Edit:

Here is a quote from the whole program optimisation documentation, which highlights the fact that linking libraries compiled with different VS versions might not work in some cases:

> The format of files produced with /GL in the current version may not be readable by subsequent versions of Visual C++. You should not ship a .lib file comprised of .obj files that were produced with /GL unless you are willing to ship copies of the .lib file for all versions of Visual C++ you expect your users to use, now and in the future.

Comment: It does say you can link libraries (and object files) built with the different toolset versions.

Comment: I suspect you could link a library using the v141 toolset with a executable using the v142 toolset as long as both were compiled with the same compiler, even though I don't see why you would want that.